# Entity Framework CTP 5 RelatedTo Attribute not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, data-annotations, code-first, entity-framework-ctp5

Using Entity Framework CTP 5 I am trying to make a list of foreign keys in my class.
But I keep getting an error which says RelatedTo can not be found.

Here is the code:

```
public class VertragsVerweis : GenericBLL
{
    [Key]
    public String Uid
    {   
        get;
        set;
    }

    public String VertagsVerweisNr
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public String Bezeichnung
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Boolean Reparatur
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [RelatedTo(RelatedProperty="Artikel")]
    public List<Artikel> Artikelen
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

This gives me the error:

> Error 2   The type or namespace name 'RelatedTo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Documents and Settings\wep\Bureaublad\WEPProject\branches\codefirst Entity Framework\BusinessLogic\BusinessLogic\VertragsVerweisBLL.cs   37  10  BusinessLogic

For some reason it DOES recognize the Key Attribute from System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations. Why does it not recognize RelatedTo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you upgrade to EF4.1 ... Perhaps your problem is solved with that. If not - update your question :)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the "RelatedTo"-Attribute did not make it into the RC. List of supported annotions is here under section 8: [ADO Team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-code-first-walkthrough.aspx)

EDIT: I found the blog entry I was looking for originaly: [EF design blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/03/30/data-annotations-in-the-entity-framework-and-code-first.aspx). "RelatedTo" is listed under "New Data Annotation Attributes", where they say that they *propose* these attributes.