# RelatedTo attribute not recognised, even after installation of Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, code-first, asp.net-mvc-4

I am busy learning ASP.Net MVC and so I recently installed MVC 4 on Visual Studio 2010 Professional. I was trying this example:

http://www.luisrocha.net/2010/11/creating-composite-keys-using-code.html

But the *RelatedTo* attribute is not found by Visual Studio. I read on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499969/entity-framework-ctp-5-relatedto-attribute-not-working) that this could be caused by Entity Framework 4.1 not being installed. I checked the version number of *System.Data.Entity.dll* and it gave version 4.0.0.0, runtime version v4.0.30319. So this seems to me to be version 4.0 of EF that is installed on my computer. I may be wrong on this though... so someone please correct me if I am.

I downloaded EF 4.1 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26825) and installed it, but the version numbers for *System.Data.Entity.dll* seem not to have changed and the *RelatedTo* attribute is still not working. Anyone know what is going wrong with the installation and how I could fix it?

**UPDATE:**

I installed Entity Framework using nuget as instructed on [this site](http://nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework), and the console said it installed *EntityFramework 5.0.0-rc*, but the version of *System.Data.Entity.dll* seems to be unchanged.

No, I did not include *using System.Data.Entity* because intellisense did not tell me to include that. I did include *System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations* and *using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema* because these were required by the *Key* and *Column* attributes. Intellisense asks me to *"Generate class for 'RelatedTo'"* and adding *using System.Data.Entity* does not change that.

Here is my code for those asking for it, although it is exactly the code from the tutorial that I linked to in the question:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Example
{
    public class PlaylistTrack
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public int PlaylistId { get; set; }

        [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
        public int TrackId { get; set; }

        [RelatedTo(ForeignKey = "PlaylistId")]
        public Playlist Playlist { get; set; }

        [RelatedTo(ForeignKey = "TrackId")]
        public Track Track { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: and you have a `using System.Data.Entity` in your file?

Comment: It's better if you can put some sample code here.. So that question is still be valuable if we have a broken link to your article.

Comment: @Jayantha Point taken about code in the question being useful if there is a broken link. I have added the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try installing new version of EF using Nuget. It will resolve all dependencies of EF and it will make sure you have the latest version. I don't know what is     `RelatedTo` attribute supposed to be doing here. And see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-code-first-walkthrough.aspx) in the data annotations section, the related to attribute is not in the EF4.1 release. But you can do the same thing like this.

```
      [ForeignKey("PlaylistId")] 
      public Playlist Playlist { get; set; }

      [ForeignKey("TrackId")] 
      public Track Track { get; set; }
```

**EDIT**
[RelatedTo attribute is  replaced by ForeignKey and InverseProperty attributes in EF 4.1 RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716528/entity-framework-4-1-inverseproperty-attribute)

Comment: +1 For telling me about _ForeignKey_. Thanks, this attribute does seem to work. And it seems to be doing the same job as the _RelatedTo_. I read about RelatedTo over here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/03/30/data-annotations-in-the-entity-framework-and-code-first.aspx. Can you (or anyone else) confirm that the _RelatedTo_ attribute has been replaced by _ForeignKey_? If that is so, then the tutorial that I linked to and the accepted answer to the question that I linked to are actually giving misinformation.